# Stopwatch for Alphabets

Tags: code-golf, game

Implement Stopwatch for typing Alphabets

**Alphabets** = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z".

**Note**

- The program should run infinitely and should stop only when **Esc** button is pressed.
- The stopwatch starts with keystroke "a" and ends with keystroke "z"
- Output is the time taken to type the **Alphabets** correctly (ie. time take for **51 keystrokes**)
- If an illegal character occurs then stopwatch should stop and print **"Failed"**
- If a new record is set then print "**!!New record!!," TimeTaken**

  where, **TimeTaken** = time taken to print alphabets correctly.

**Winner:** One with the shortest code.

Comment: What do you mean by "new record"? Is the alphabet typed in over and over again?

Comment: yes, the program will run till we press "Esc"

Comment: @Codingman How exactly is the record supposed to be saved?

Comment: I created something like this a while back: https://ethproductions.github.io/type/ Level 15 is the alphabet.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica, 303

Here with white-space and expanded symbols.
Everything happens in the `Switch` statement of the `EventHandler` where I pattern match `{pressed key, next letter}`.

Might want to replace the `Quit` with something less sinister before hitting escape:

```
z := AbsoluteTime[];
f = "a"; y = Dynamic;
DynamicModule[{
  a = f~CharacterRange~"z", c = 1, d = f, r = \[Infinity]},
 EventHandler[
  y@d~InputField~String,
  "KeyDown" :> Switch[
    {CurrentValue@"EventKey", a[[c]]},
    {f ..},
      t = z; c++; d = y@a[[c]],
    {"z" ..}, 
      t = z - t;
      d = If[t < r,
         r = t; "!!New record!!,",
         ""] ~~ ToString@t;
      c = 1,
    {a_, a_},
      c++,
    {"\[RawEscape]", _}, Quit[],
    _, d = "Failed"; c = 1]]]
```

Comment: I apologize. "!!New record!!, TimeTaken" is not string completely. Instead, it is "!!New record!!," TimeTaken. TimeTaken is variable storing the time taken. I am not aware of Mathematica. I hope, you will handle it correctly

Comment: @Codingman Oh, I should have figured, just mindless copy+paste :)

Answer (score 4):

### C, 181

Note that in order for this to work, your terminal must be setup to not buffer characters.  One possible linux solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar).  Should this be considered part of my code?

```
double t,c,r=2<<29;main(l){for(;l<27&&96+l++==(c=getchar());)l==2&&time(&t);if(c==27)return;t=difftime(time(),t);l-27?puts("Failed"):t<r&&printf("!!New record!! %f\n",r=t);main(1);}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 182

```
use Term::ReadKey;ReadMode 3;@a=a..z;while(1){$c=getc;$s=time if!$i;last if$c eq"\e";if($c ne$a[$i++]){print"Failed";last}if($i==@a){print"!!New record!!,",(time-$s);last}}ReadMode 0
```

There's probably room for improvement. I could also remove the `ReadMode 0` from the end, saving 10 chars. In addition, it's not clear to me if the use of `Term::ReadKey` is OK or not for the Code Golf. If it's not, then I don't think that this particular golf can be solved with Perl.

Same program written properly and in a readable fashion:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ReadKey;
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
ReadMode 3;
my @a=('a'..'z');
my $i=0;
my $s;
while (1) {
    my $c=ReadKey(0);
    $s=time if !$i;
    last if $c eq "\e";
    if ($c ne $a[$i++]) {
        print "Failed";
        last;
    }
    if ($i==@a) {
        print "!!New record!!,",(time-$s);
        last;
    }
}
ReadMode 0;
```